# Cannot assign to value: 'user' is a 'let' constant - FIXED

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a login page where user logs in with Auth Email/Password and if they are declared admin or user the performSegue takes to a different page.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let email = txtemail.text, let passowrd = txtpass.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: passowrd) { (user, error) in
            Database.database().reference().child("user").child("admin")
            if user = true {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "adminlogin", sender : self)
            }
            if user = false {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender : self)
            }
        }
    }
```

However keeps coming up with this error:

> Cannot assign to value: 'user' is a 'let' constant

ANSWERED:

I fixed this by doing this to my code:

```
{ Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: passowrd) { (user, error) in
            if user != nil {
            let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                Database.database().reference().child("user").child(uid!).child("admin").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    // Checking if user is found
                    if snapshot.exists() {
                        // admin is found
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "adminlogin", sender : self)
                    } else {
                        // admin is not found going to user login
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender : self)
                    }
                })
```

Now when I log in with Admin I go to another View Controller, than if I log in with a User.

Comment: You should simply this by checking `if condition { ... } else { }`. Also, `user` needs a better name. What does it mean for `user` to be `true` or `false`? Somethinng better would be `userIsAdmin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is used as an assignment operator

`==` is the comparison operator

You want to use `==` to make the comparison.

The user and error objects are immutable, meaning you can't change them. But they are holding values that you want to check.

I've updated your code to work:

```
 @IBAction func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let email = txtemail.text, let passowrd = txtpass.text

    {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: passowrd) { (user, error) in
            Database.database().reference().child("user").child("admin")
            if user == true {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "adminlogin", sender : self)
            }
            if user == false {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender : self)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: getting the error " Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AuthDataResult?' and 'Bool' "

Answer (score 1):

You have put `if user = true` A single `=` is an assignment. To check a value is equal to something use `if user == true`

Comment: Sadly getting the error  " Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AuthDataResult?' and 'Bool "

Comment: So `user` isn't a Bool?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to swift. I don't think so, however I think it should be as its either a true or false statement.

Comment: You can only test if something is true or false if the `user` is itself a Bool. If `user` is not a Bool then you cannot. Are you trying to determine if `user` exists (i.e. is not nil)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't check if the user is an admin or not by comparing it to true or false. I suggest to log the user in and after that validating if the UID is an admin by so:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "user/admin/(UID after logged in)")

databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    // Checking if user is found
    if snapshot.exists() {
        // admin is found 
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "adminlogin", sender : self)
    } else {
        // admin is not found going to user login
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender : self)
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail please. As to where shall I put this code in the actual logged in page?